# how can I set the value Present Value in my class to be called into a Method

Tags: java, eclipse, class, methods

I am currently trying to pull the return value from the PresentValue Method in the FutureValue method for calculation.

I tried to fix the problem by declaring pv1 and just using the value. The new problem is that it is being set to 0.

Does anyone know how I can fix this issue or at least be able to use the value returned from present value?

```
public class Bank1 {

    private double cash;
    private double rate = .0425;
    private int years;

    public Bank1(double cash, int years){
        this.cash = cash;
        this.years = years;     
    }

    private double pv1 = cash/Math.pow((1+rate), years);

    public double PresentValue(){
        double pv = cash/Math.pow((1+rate), years);
        double present = Math.round(pv *100);
        present = present/100;
        return present;
    }


    public double  FutureValue(){
        double fv = pv1*Math.pow((1+rate), years);
        double future = Math.round(fv *100);
        future = future/100;
        return future;
    }   

}
```

The output is just a call to the methods.

the output I am receiving is

How much money would you like to have?
100

How many years is your investment? 1

$100.0 is the amount you want.

$95.92 is the amount you would need to invest

$0.0 would be your future value

thanks for any help!!

Comment: You are not actually calling your `PresentValue()` method. And by the way, only type names should begin with a capital letter. Methods, variables and fields should start with a lowercase letter (except constants, which are all caps).

Comment: thank you for your comment. I will change the name types to the correct assignments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just change **pv1*Math.pow((1+rate), years);**

for **this.PresentValue()*Math.pow((1+rate), years);**

```
public class Bank1 {

private double cash;
private double rate = .0425;
private int years;

public Bank1(double cash, int years){
    this.cash = cash;
    this.years = years;     
}

private double pv1 = cash/Math.pow((1+rate), years);

public double PresentValue(){
    double pv = cash/Math.pow((1+rate), years);
    double present = Math.round(pv *100);
    present = present/100;
    return present;
}


public double  FutureValue(){
    double fv = this.PresentValue()*Math.pow((1+rate), years);
    double future = Math.round(fv *100);
    future = future/100;
    return future;
}   

public static void main(String args[]){
    Bank1 bank = new Bank1(100.0, 1);
    System.out.println("PresentValue: " + bank.PresentValue());
    System.out.println("FutureValue: " + bank.FutureValue());
}

}
```

Comment: thank you, this helped alot. I will apply the same technique for other calculations. Thank you again.

Comment: for nothing , I'm happy to have helped

Answer (score 1):

Give `FutureValue` a parameter so you can pass in the results:

```
public double FutureValue(double value) {
    //use value
}
```

When you call it, pass in the value returned from `PresentValue`:

```
double value = PresentValue();
double futureValue = FutureValue(value);
```

By convention, method names (identifiers) should start with a lowercase letter. The only things that should start with an uppercase letter are type identifiers (class/enum/interface names) or constants (static final variables)

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways you could go with this, but seeing as your class is immutable, the best way is probably to pre-calculate the present and future values in the constructor and then simply return them from accessor methods. Note that I'm also passing presentValue into calculateFutureValue():

```
public class Bank1 {

    private double cash;
    private double rate = .0425;
    private int years;
    private double presentValue;
    private double futureValue;

    public Bank1(double cash, int years){
        this.cash = cash;
        this.years = years;
        presentValue = calculatePresentValue();
        futureValue = calculateFutureValue(presentValue);
    }

    private double calculatePresentValue(){
        double pv = cash/Math.pow((1+rate), years);
        double present = Math.round(pv *100);
        present = present/100;
        return present;
    }

    private double calculateFutureValue(final double value){
        double fv = value*Math.pow((1+rate), years);
        double future = Math.round(fv *100);
        future = future/100;
        return future;
    }  

    public double getPresentValue() {
        return presentValue;
    }

    public double getFutureValue() {
        return futureValue;
    } 

}
```